# Liquidsoap Syntax Highlighting for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, liquidsoap

I could not find any official Syntax Definition for Sublime Text 3, 
to highlight [Liquidsoap](https://www.liquidsoap.info) files (`*.liq`).

Since I understand TextMate bundles are somehow compatible, I found this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vittee/8227f1f7311d1db8aab49fb84c39fa79), which I copied to the `/sublime-text/packages/liquidsoap/liquidsoap.tmLanguage` but this didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?